# Is there any way to reset the whole viewController hierachy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a viewController A which will both added into viewController hierarchy by being pushed by view B(presented) and being pushed by view C(pushed).

ROOT->...-(-present-)->B-(-push-)->A

ROOT->...-(-push-)->C-(-push-)->A

And now I have a button in viewController A which needs to change the **window.rootViewController**, but I cannot make it functions correct in both conditions.

When I use `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:<#(BOOL)#>];`, it will not dismiss the presented view B.

Also `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:<#^(void)completion#>];` is not the solution, because when there is no presented view completion block will not be called.

If I combine those two methods, I think it will work only when I pass a parameter to every viewController in the hierarchy.

So is there a rough way to clear the viewController hierarchy? 
Or is there any other solution?

Comment: you want to go view controller C to view controller A?

Comment: @Tepmnthar:  Why presented view B will be dismissed? For that you have to manually write `[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` and why the rootviewcontroller will be dismissed? Rootviewcontroller will never be dismissed or popped.

Comment: just reload the rootview controller again.

Comment: @Saurabh Jain I want to replace rootViewController when A is on the top of the viewController hierarchy

Comment: @Poles
 sorry for my description to the question.
I know rootViewController will always be in the hierarchy, I just want to replace it.

If I dont dismiss view controller B, after I replace rootViewController, presented view will not be removed.

Comment: @CodeHunterr Could you provide more details, please.

Comment: @Tepmnthar: Just replace the current rootviewcontroller with the same rootviewcontroller..it will reload all view controllers in navigation hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `rootViewController` from anywhere in application like,

```
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 appDelegate.window.rootViewController = @"desired root VC"; // instatntiate your VC and set as root VC of your window
```

And don't forget to implement `AppDelegate.h` in that class.

Comment: My current stuff is something just like this. But when facing the first condition, both `current view` and `desired root VC` will in the new hierarchy. I dont know why, maybe presented view can only be removed by `dismiss`.